Designing a Distributed System for Indigenous Data Sovereignty Across Nations
I'm looking for some quick "back-of-the-napkin" thoughts from systems engineers on the following scenario:
A collection of Indigenous groups (in the US, Canada, and Australia) want to design a distributed system that connects them. The system should adhere to Indigenous data sovereignty and will involve groups from multiple countries.
Going open source is key, but are there particular tech stacks they should consider that might be more useful for working across multiple countries?
What are some of the key challenges they might face in terms of data governance, since the project may involve data sets from multiple countries/stakeholders?
Some of the grounding principles and ideas that are framing their process: OCAP (Ownership, Control, Access, Possession) and FAIR (findable, accessible, interoperable, reusable) and CARE (Collective Benefit, Authority to Control, Responsibility, Ethics)
Thanks in advance for your insights!

"want to experiment with AI and design a distributed system that connects them" These appear to be two unrelated goals with very different requirements.  Is there something more to how one relates to other?

Not sure yet! It could be that the system is about distrubing data that is USED for AI models, or alternatively, for sharing programs/algorithms and ML models.

I would separate those two goals, then. They are both totally valid, and one can support the other, but nothing inherently binds them together. Each of those problems is complex enough on its own.

Let's say it's the first: a system for distributing shared data. Do you have thoughts on how to design the system in a way that aligns with larger Indigenous Data Sovereignty goals? :-)

I'll be honest: I don't know whether or how 'indigenous data sovereignty goals' are different from 'data sovereignty goals' in general. But my first thought is: open source.  My second thought is that you would want the kind of open source (and organizations working on it) that aligns with the values of these communities.

Third thought: how much dependency on non-indigenous resources can be tolerated?  For true sovereignty, you need to control the equipment, power, and support. I recall reading that there are major poker sites run out of Inuit areas of Canada. They might be a resource.

But that might be limit unless you are going to build chip-fabs. We are all connected and interdependent at some level these days.

Appreciate all these comments/thoughts, @JimmyJames

This sounds like homework that you've disguised as if it's a professional endeavour, or a business babbly wishlist completely lacking in any technical foundation that provides no information on concrete business goals. It's either off-topic and/or not meaningfully answerable, on top of way too broad and vague. I'm not sure which close vote best applies but it's definitely one of them.

Part of the reason why I'm betting on homework here is because there's specific requirements being listed without any justification as to why, and having knowledge of these concepts (in order to be able to list them as important requirements) implies some kind of technical understanding that is then oddly absent from the information that would reveal how to build towards that goal. This is exactly how educational exercises are designed: list specific criteria, give no information on how to achieve them on the supposition that this information was already provided elsewhere (i.e. in class).

Oh and furthermore, AI and data sovereignty find themselves on starkly different ends of the spectrum in terms of accessibility of data.

Here is a technology of the 80's that could be applied to the task:
usenet
Let there be a community of servers,
with indigenous roots or otherwise, that agree to
gossip
with one another,
flooding
messages via
NNTP
or a similar protocol.
Each message, or "article", will have a unique Article-ID: header
of the form guid@domain.name.
Each article author will have a private GPG key or similar, and
will attach a publicly verifiable RSA signature to each new article.
Here's what was not present in the Usenet of the 80's:
a common governance structure.
Plus servers might not honor every well-formed Cancel message.
Spin up some non-profit corporation which implements
the will of members, however you choose to define that.
When disagreements arise it will ajudicate them.
When they join, members should agree to send articles
of limited size at some limited rate, on topics of
mutual interest. So for example, no hate speech.
Articles are always signed using Author's private key.
Sometimes an author will send an article to flood through the network,
then think better of it,
and subsequently send a
Cancel
message which also floods through the network,
requesting deletion at each server that receives it.
This addresses some of your "Ownership, Control" concerns.
Members should agree to always honor such Cancel messages.
You might possibly wish for articles to routinely have
an Expires: datestamp header, which members agree to honor.
And then author could routinely issue weekly updates which extend
the expiration date by seven days.
This gets into a Library of Alexandria digital archivist issue:
do we want neglected volumes to burn, to spontaneously combust
after their expiration date?
Authors and readers may have different perspectives on this.

This system must respect Indigenous data sovereignty and self-determination

I disagree with that statement, as it is infeasible.
We can build systems that are large and fancy, but ultimately
a given system is dumb.
It has no notion of the concepts you're articulating.
What you need is corporate governance which implements
the desires of members, which may align with those notions.
And then the deployed system should do what was jointly decided.
